# SPARK:Compression of shuffle map output files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have compressed data of size 500GB(uncompressed size is around 3TB) .I am repartitioning this data since the underlying data is very skewed and is causing a lot of issues for the downstream jobs.
During repartioning the shuffles writes are not getting compressed due to this I am running into disk space issues in the cluster.Below is the screen shot which clearly depicts the issue(Input,shuffle write columns)
I have proactively set below parameters to true, but still it doesn’t compress the intermediate shuffled data

spark.shuffle.compress

spark.shuffle.spill.compress

[image]

I am using Spark 1.5 (for various unavoidable reasons!!)
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is adding more disk space a problem? What execution environment are you using?

Comment: I think there isn't a strict equivalence between the size of your data compressed and the the amount of data shuffled, because 1) the data shuffled has usually been through some transformation of any kind which could _increase_ its volume post-processing (think of a cartesian product), 2) the compression of smaller chunks could be less efficient than the whole 3 TB (depending on the structure of the data exchanged), 3) data can be over-shuffled if the transformations applied to the RDD are under-efficient and generate extra workload. This list is not exhaustive.